# elm-make can't find files after moving files into subdirectory

Tags: elm, elm-make

I refactored my Elm code to be located in the src directory. And I updated elm-package.json to have `"source-directories": [
        "src"
    ],`

However, now when I run `elm-make Main.elm` I get this error message:

`elm-make: Main.elm: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

Is there another configuration somewhere else I need to make to have elm-make be able to find my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still need `elm-make src/Main.elm` as that is being run from the command line, but now any import statements in Main.elm will be looked up in src/...

Comment: omg, I swear I tried that, but I must not have because it's working.